What is the Chinam Klipa
BH
Hi I was told about a klipa explained in Chassidus called chinam where a person wants everything for free without work. Where does it talk about this? What is the sources in Chassidus?

Chassidus explains on זכרנו את הדאגה אשר נאכל במצרים חינם that it's much easier to receive from kelipah than from kedusha. See e.g. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60793&st=&pgnum=238.
